# Azure Search on searching articles with images

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-search

I have 500+ articles with Images, I want to retrieve those articles with images and show the same in in chatbot using Microsoft bot Framework and Azure Search. But, Azure search isn't able to index images. In this scenario where do I need to store these images, how do I map these images to appropriate article?

Answer (score 0):

You can either populate the documents in the index via code or use an indexer that can create your documents.  Here is the Indexer data source drop down showing the different data sources available.
[image]

You could put the information about the image and a path to the image in any of these data sources and have an indexer pick it up and create your documents within the index.

If you don't want to use a formal database, you could also upload your images into blob storage and decorate each blob with custom metadata.  When creating your index with an indexer, it will find the custom metadata and it can become fields on documents within your index.

There are lots of options, but my advice is to keep your documents within your index as small as possible to control your costs.  That's usually done by having as few a fields as possible and have fields that reference where the stuff is located.  The documents within an index are for discovering where things are located and NOT for storing the actual data.  When you index start occupying lots of space, your cost will go up a LOT.